# i want to show the confirm message from the server side then on the "OK" or "Cancel" event i want to execute a server side method

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, telerik

I have a button like this:-

```
<telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </telerik:RadScriptManager>  
    <telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="mainAjaxPanelContentManager" runat="server" Height="100%" LoadingPanelID="contentManagerRadAjaxLoadingPanel" OnAjaxRequest="ContentManagerAjaxRequest"></telerik:RadAjaxPanel>


<asp:ImageButton ID="btnadd" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Done.png" 
        Height="20px" OnClientClick="test()"/>
```

then i have javascript function like this:-

```
function test() 
{
    var result;
    var r = confirm("Duplicate Serial Number - DO you want to change it?");
    $find("<%= mainAjaxPanelContentManager.ClientID %>").ajaxRequest(r);    
}
```

which successfully runs following server side method:-

```
protected void ContentManagerAjaxRequest(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.AjaxRequestEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Argument.ToLower() == "true")
        {
        }
    }
```

But when i do like this:-

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnadd" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Done.png" 
        Height="20px" OnClick="btnadd_Click"/>

protected void btnadd_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        showMessageBox("Hello");
    }

    protected void showMessageBox(string message)
    {
        string sScript = "";
        sScript += "var result;";
        sScript += "var r = confirm('Duplicate Serial Number - DO you want to change it');";       
        sScript += mainAjaxPanelContentManager + ".ajaxRequest(r);";


        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "confirm", sScript, true);


    }
```

then it not execute server side method `ContentManagerAjaxRequest` and throws an exception that "Object doesn't support this property or method".

i think `ajaxRequest()` not supported on serverside. but wahts is its alter native?

actually my problem is that i want to show the confirm message from the server side then on the "OK" or "Cancel" event i want to execute a server side method like "`ContentManagerAjaxRequest`"

Answer (score 1):

```
sScript += mainAjaxPanelContentManager + ".ajaxRequest(r);";
```

What is that supposed to do?

Don't you want something like this (which you already did in the beginning)?

```
sScript += mainAjaxPanelContentManager.ClientID + ".ajaxRequest(r);";
```

Comment: yes i have already tried with this sScript += mainAjaxPanelContentManager.ClientID + ".ajaxRequest(r);"; . But still see the same exception. Dont know how to do this on server side. On the Client side $find("<%= mainAjaxPanelContentManager.ClientID %>").ajaxRequest(r); runs successfully